# In Android, how can you get the last used/open date of an application?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a statistics application like function. how can you get the last used/open date of an application? Is there a property in ApplicationInfo?

Thanks

Comment: would you like to do this for your own app or for all the applications on the device?

Comment: See here: [Launch Time of an app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324847/launch-time-of-an-app#answer-2326191). You can do it by hands.

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205952/how-to-get-last-opened-date-of-an-application-in-android

Comment: @Francescoverheye I would like to do this on all the app in a device.

Comment: Hi do you mind sharing how you did this??

Comment: Sure what is your email address so I can send you the doc

Comment: @objectiveCarlo Have you found a solution?