# How do I know when any of installed app was last used programmatically?

Tags: android

How do I know when an app was last used in Android? Is it possible to determine this? and how to get last used date?

Comment: I think it's possible, but I don't know how

Comment: If you are developing an app then you can add the mentioned functionality. I'm not sure about the same with the other apps.

Comment: I don't know it is exactly what you want, but did you see the following links?
 Maybe it can be. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986542/in-android-how-can-you-get-the-last-used-open-date-of-an-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205952/how-to-get-last-opened-date-of-an-application-in-android

Comment: For example : I want to get when last time facebook app used, or when "Some App, Not mine" last used, last opened

Answer (score 5):

you can use get the usuage of app using UsageStatsManager

Manifest.Java

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button statsBtn;
    TextView status;
    Context mContext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        mContext = MainActivity.this;
        //Check if permission enabled
        if (UStats.getUsageStatsList(this).isEmpty()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        statsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stats_btn);
        statsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //  UStats.printCurrentUsageStatus(MainActivity.this);
                status.setText(UStats.printUsageStatus(mContext));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Ustats.Java

/**
 * Created by User on 3/2/15.
 */

```
public class UStats {
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M-d-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    public static final String TAG = UStats.class.getSimpleName();
    @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
    public static void getStats(Context context) {
        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService("usagestats");
        int interval = UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_YEARLY;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        long endTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
        long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        Log.d(TAG, "Range start:" + dateFormat.format(startTime));
        Log.d(TAG, "Range end:" + dateFormat.format(endTime));
        UsageEvents uEvents = usm.queryEvents(startTime, endTime);
        while (uEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
            UsageEvents.Event e = new UsageEvents.Event();
            uEvents.getNextEvent(e);
            if (e != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Event: " + e.getPackageName() + "\t" + e.getTimeStamp());
            }
        }
    }
    public static List<UsageStats> getUsageStatsList(Context context) {
        UsageStatsManager usm = getUsageStatsManager(context);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        long endTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
        long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        Log.d(TAG, "Range start:" + dateFormat.format(startTime));
        Log.d(TAG, "Range end:" + dateFormat.format(endTime));
        List<UsageStats> usageStatsList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, startTime, endTime);
        return usageStatsList;
    }
    public void printUsageStats(List<UsageStats> usageStatsList) {
        String value = null;
        for (UsageStats u : usageStatsList) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Pkg: " + u.getPackageName() + "\t" + "ForegroundTime: "
                    + u.getTotalTimeInForeground());
            value = "Pkg: " + u.getPackageName() + "\t" + "ForegroundTime: " + u.getTotalTimeInForeground();
        }
    }
    public void printCurrentUsageStatus(Context context) {
        printUsageStats(getUsageStatsList(context));
    }
    public static String printUsageStatus(Context context) {
        return printUsageStatss(getUsageStatsList(context));
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
    private static UsageStatsManager getUsageStatsManager(Context context) {
        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService("usagestats");
        return usm;
    }
    public static String printUsageStatss(List<UsageStats> usageStatsList) {
        String value = null;
        for (UsageStats u : usageStatsList) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Pkg: " + u.getPackageName() + "\t" + "ForegroundTime: "
                    + u.getTotalTimeInForeground());
            value = "Pkg: " + u.getPackageName() + "\t" + "ForegroundTime: " + u.getTotalTimeInForeground();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [UsageStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats.html#getLastTimeUsed())

```
if( mUsageStats.getPackageName().equals("YOUR PACKAGE NAME")){
    mUsageStats.getLastTimeUsed();
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats.html#getLastTimeUsed()

Comment: Is there a way to find out when the device was last used instead of a particular app?